# How to keep the same height of a dynamic html document on every device

Tags: android, html, css, printing

I have an html page which I print through different android devices. The height of the page is changing dynamically depending on some labels that I update through Javascript. Then I pass the height of the page to the android so I can set the height of the page that will be printed.(Dimensions are 856x3000ish pixels). My problem is that when I am trying to print the document from a bigger screen mobile device then the device pixel ratio is 200%-300% but when I am trying to print the same document from older smaller devices the ratio is 150%, so in every device(and on different browsers or same browsers with different zoom) the html page gets a different height. This has as a result the printer to behave differently depending on the different height. So for example: if I print from a device with 100% aspect ratio my print is perfect but if I print from a device that has 200% aspect ratio then my document is not printed properly and some centimeters at the end of it are not printed at all. I am pretty confident that the problem is the different aspect ratio of the different devices that make the height of the html page to change. How do I keep the same height of the html page no matter what the aspect ratio of the screen is? Any other suggestion is welcome.

```
@page { 
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'customFont'; 
    src: url("../fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");    
}

html {
    transform-origin: center;
    font-family: 'customFont';
    line-height: 1.2em;
}

#mainBody {
    height: 100%;
    padding:0px !important;
    margin:0px;
}


form {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 840px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border: 2px solid;
}

label {
    border: hidden;
    font-size: 18.5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce the next line in the `<head>` of your html file:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Next you can add in css the value of "height": 100vh.

VH stands for “viewport height”. So you always keep 100% of the height no matter what device.

The content would remain dynamic in my example. But if you want just a fixed size no matter what device you have to work with px.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it did not work for me because this scales the whole page to fit my viewport height but my html page must keep the same height(which is longer that viewport height in most cases) no matter the viewport dimensions.